# Copy block of text from webpage using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've extracted a whole web page as text and that text is assigned to a variable. Now I need to select a portion of that text and assign it to another variable. Let's say, the text I have is:

```
Note: Your feedback is very important to us, however, we do not
respond to individual submissions through this channel. If you require
support, please visit the Safety & Security Center. Follow: Change log
for version 1.211.2457.0 This page shows you what's changed in the
most recent definitions update for Microsoft antimalware and
antispyware software. 

You can also see changes in the last 20 updates from the Change
definition version menu on the right.

The latest update is:
1.211.2457.0
Download the latest update.

Â New definitions (?)



Antimalware (Antivirus + Antispyware)
```

I would like the following text to be assigned to a variable

```
1.211.2457.0
```

The code I have for now is

```
$URI = "http://www.example.com/mynewpage"
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
$WebPageText = ($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("div") | Where-Object{$_.className -eq "span bp0-col-1-1 bp1-col-1-1 bp2-col-1-1 bp3-col-1-1"}).innerText
```

I tried `Select-String -SimpleMatch "The latest update is:*Download the latest update." -InputObject $WebPageText`, but I'm pretty sure that's wrong.
I'm new to PowerShell scripting. So please pardon me if I'm missing something obvious.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SimpleMatch` would ignore any regex metacharaters. It would not allow *any* wildcards either. From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx):

> Uses a simple match rather than a regular expression match. In a simple match, Select-String searches the input for the text in the Pattern parameter. **It does not interpret the value** of the Pattern parameter as a regular expression statement

What you could do is use regex to find a string where the line only contains digits and periods: `"^[\d\.]+$"`.

```
$version = ($WebPageText | Select-String "^[\d\.]+$").Matches.Value
```

It is possible more that one could be returned so you might need to account for that.

If you wanted a more targeted (but no guaranteed unique result) you could just use the `-match` operator.

```
If(($WebPageText | out-string) -match "(?sm)The latest update is:\s+(.*?)\s+Download the latest update"){
    $version = $Matches[1]
}
```

Comment: Or more precise pattern like that: "The latest update is:\r?\n(.*?)\r?\nDownload the latest update." "

Comment: @Uriel I was going for simple based on the text shown. No guarantee even that text "The latest update is..." is not repeated in a dump

Comment: @Matt, thank you! `-Match` worked! The information I'm looking for on our web page is displayed only once on the page, so that solution works.
However, `$version = ($WebPageText | Select-String "^[\d\.]+$").Matches.Value` for some reason, did not give me any result. I'll look for some documentation on RegEx in PowerShell.

Comment: I had to guess with the regex since I didnt have real data to test with. Could have easily been some whitespace there I did not account for. Glad it worked out.